# Submitting form with disabled input

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I'm wondering if I can get some assistance. I have a form that I want to submit data to a database. However, I am getting an issue doing so with the following code. The select inputs are set to disabled so if nothing is selected then the form doesn't submit those fields (fields by default are still submitted blank.

```
<div class="form-group">
        <label for="title">
                Title
                    <span class="asteriskField">
                          *
                     </span>
        </label>
        <select id="inputtitle" name="title" class="form-control" onchange="updateReview('title');" tabindex=1 />
                    <option value="" selected disabled>Please select</option>
                    <option value="Master">Master</option>
                    <option value="Mr">Mr</option>
                    <option value="Mrs">Mrs</option>
                    <option value="Miss">Miss</option>
                    <option value="Ms">Ms</option>
                    <option value="Rev.">Rev.</option>
        </select>
</div>
```

Thank you.

Comment: What's the behavior you're trying to achieve?

Comment: You can use an input hidden with the value there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using disabled on option in selectbox isn't good solution, because it does not force user to select option. If he does not click on selectbox, blank value will be posted.

To force user to select option use `required` on selectbox, and also leave default option disabled, so he will have to choose one option.

Answer (score 0):

use Form `OnSubmit` event and create formdata manually in javascript with the fields you want to send to server based on conditions.

Answer (score 0):

This is simply the way forms work in HTML. When you submit a form, all the input fields are retrieved and sent to the designated action. However, selectboxes that were not selected are not part of the post.

If you want to send a list of all select boxes (including the ones that are unselected), a common trick is to create a hidden input with the same value for each selectbox. This way you get a list of all the selected fields, as well as the entire list of selectable fields.

Answer (score 0):

It's a wrong behavior, you should validate if nothing it's selected with javascript or some backend code before any query into DB. Don't use disabled in fields that you want, in some way, retrieve some kind of data, because you're changing the intrinsic behavior of the element, confusing the next guy that will work with your code.

If nothing is selected you can return false into your backend with some error message or just disable the visualization of submit button with javascript.

EDIT: The solution from @Autista_z is good about

> To force user to select option use required on selectbox, and also leave default option disabled, so he will have to choose one option.

I just want to empathize: don't let the backend without that validation too, double validation (front/back) is a **must**.